# Trouble with creating first Substrate chain

Tags: blockchain, substrate

When I try to compile the Node Template I get a series of errors.
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v2.0.0 (/Users/Modulus3D/VSCode Projects/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/Modulus3D/VSCode Projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-cae9ad6029c9f681/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stdout
Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/Modulus3D/VSCode Projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--release"

and also:

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
--> /Users/Modulus3D/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
|
541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
|                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type
...
1595 | / implement_fixed!(
1596 | |     FixedI64,
1597 | |     test_fixed_i64,
1598 | |     i64,
...    |
1601 | |     "*Fixed Point 64 bits signed, range = [-9223372036.854775808, 9223372036.854775807]*",
1602 | | );
| |__- in this macro invocation
|
= note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
--> /Users/Modulus3D/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
|
541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
|                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type
...
1604 | / implement_fixed!(
1605 | |     FixedI128,
1606 | |     test_fixed_i128,
1607 | |     i128,
...    |
1611 | |         [-170141183460469231731.687303715884105728, 170141183460469231731.687303715884105727]_",
1612 | | );
| |__- in this macro invocation
|
= note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
--> /Users/Modulus3D/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sp-arithmetic-2.0.0/src/fixed_point.rs:541:9
|
541  |                   let accuracy = P::ACCURACY.saturated_into();
|                       ^^^^^^^^ consider giving `accuracy` a type
...
1614 | / implement_fixed!(
1615 | |     FixedU128,
1616 | |     test_fixed_u128,
1617 | |     u128,
...    |
1621 | |         [0.000000000000000000, 340282366920938463463.374607431768211455]_",
1622 | | );
| |__- in this macro invocation
|
= note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
error: could not compile `sp-arithmetic`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed

Any suggestions on how to resolve these errors??

Comment: Are you building with the nightly specified here? https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template#build

Answer (score 1):

Look like you need to downgrade you nightly version.

You can do so by running the following sequence of commands:

```sh
rustup install nightly-2020-10-06
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-10-06
export WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN=nightly-2020-10-06
```

You can learn more about how nightly is used with substrate here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/#rust-nightly-toolchain

Answer (score 0):

Fresh project always facing the efferent nightly versions issue.
If you running the substrate version 2.0.0 you can solve it with bellow command:

```
rustup install nightly-2020-07-02
rustup override set nightly-2020-07-02
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-07-02
```

then try to re build again!